# Add or subtract numbers to find the smallest non-negative integer

Tags: fastest-algorithm

Given a positive integer, `n`, along with `n` non-negative integers, write a program or function that prints or returns the smallest non-negative integer that can be obtained by additions and subtractions between those numbers. You must use all of the input numbers.

The winner is the algorithm with the smallest big O time complexity. Ties will be broken by shortest code, in bytes. Please post your time complexity and your byte count along with your submission.

**Examples**

Input: `5` `14 16 20 10 2`
Output: `2`

Two is the smallest number that can be obtained by adding or subtracting the given numbers, as shown by `16 + 14 - 20 - 10 + 2 = 2`.

Input: `4` `1 1 1 1`
Output: `0`

Input: `1` `0`
Output: `0`

Input: `3` `100 50 49`
Output: `1`

Comment: What is 'fastest'?

Comment: It's the fastest algorithm

Comment: The [tag](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/fastest-algorithm/info) suggests that it's the smallest big O time complexity. Is that what you are intending?

Comment: Yes, the challenge is to find the smallest big O complexity algorithm

Comment: Seems like grading by big O complexity will result in lots of many-way ties. How will these be resolved? Am I correct in assuming that every number in the input must be used exactly once?

Comment: I was thinking about that. It can't be execution time, so it should be the length of the code

Comment: Can you add a couple more examples?

Comment: This is the optimzation version of the [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is NP-hard, so you won't be getting any polynomial-time algorithms.

Comment: There's two parameters at play here: the number of numbers, and their sizes. Different algorithms could make tradeoffs in the two. How will they be compared? (The complexity-theory default is to consider the bit-length of the input.)